# Why did this question not get any votes in the last 5.5 months despite getting 61 views and comments from at least 3 different people?

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, specific-question

This is a question about a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question): [Force convergence in Wannier orbitals based DFT code](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8837/5)

I am curious to hear opinions about why this question didn't deserve any votes over such a long period of time? My vote is the only vote on this question, which I find highly unusual for MMSE, which is a site in which there's usually ***far more*** votes on questions. I don't see anything specifically wrong with this question which would warrant for it to be close-voted or not voted on.

If you could please share any insights with my about this, it might help me understand broader patterns that I've seen lately such as explained here (still with no responses): [Why have people stopped voting?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/5).

There's a few reasons why I'm curious about this, for example:

- Is it ***me*** that might be voting too leniently?
- The change in the voting frequency and voting habits makes things ***unfair*** for newer users. Do we want to have a community where early adopters got 5k rep without much effort, and now have all the voting/reviewing/moderation powers over the newer users who might have done much more for the community and put much more effort in, but still only got 1k rep due to the change in voting habits? I don't: I'd prefer for newer users to be voted on just like people were voted on in the earlier days, so that it's more fair.

Comment: Having rummaged more through the unanswered queue in the last 20 minutes, I noticed that this question was asked slightly before something happened on this site (from the community management team) which might have caused a lot of users to become inactive. It does seem that activity declined in that month at least, but other questions from around the same time still got more votes than just ***one***, even when they were much shorter and involved far less effort, so I'm very curious what was wrong with this one.